# How to set/unset multiple accounts for API credentials

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, oop, core-data

I have an app that saves multiple user accounts for retrieving data from my API. There is always one account set to be active or flagged TRUE. When I select a different account I deactivate previously active account and activate selected account or set it to be TRUE. I do these using CoreData in my Accounts table view.

When my app starts my API class checks my CoreData to see which account is active and assigns its credentials to my `Credential` object.
I then use these credentials to access and get data from my server. All works perfect until this point.

My problem is when I select a different account and reset my `Credentials` object in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, my API class still has the previously active account's credentials. I can see/print the `Credentials` object has the selected account's credentials.

How do I adjust my objects to have/use only selected account's credentials?

```
class API {
    var credentials:Credentials!
    init(){
        self.credentials = getActiveStore()
        // I use self.credentials.username to make API calls later in the code
    }


 func getActiveStore() -> Credentials?{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "active = %@", 1 as NSNumber) 
    var error:NSError?

    let fetchResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [User]
    if fetchResults.count == 1 {
        let name = fetchResults[0].name
        let url = fetchResults[0].url
        let username = fetchResults[0].username
        let password = fetchResults[0].password
        return Credentials(name: name, url: url, username: username, password: password)
    }
    return nil
}

}
```

Now this is the class that never changes. When I refresh my data after selecting a different account, the data I see belongs to previously active account. API class doesn't want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating a new credentials every time you select a new cell? Because you credentials gets update just in the criation of the object

```
init(){
    self.credentials = getActiveStore()
    // I use self.credentials.username to make API calls later in the code
}
```

If you want credentials to be update a new instance of your API has to be created.

Another way is to create an update method and call it when a new cell is selected

```
func updateCredentials(){
    self.credentials = getActiveStore()
    // I use self.credentials.username to make API calls later in the code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes simple things like this I cannot think. This is the 3rd time I asked this question and finally somebody understood.

Comment: Sometimes all we need a fresh pair of eyes to say things we miss. I'm just glad I could help. Good luck finishing your app